# Searching for a distance metric or distance similarity to compare two arrays of counts

Tags: similarities, cosine-similarity

Every object in my dataset is described as a vector of n = 200 continuous counts. I need to choose a measure to evaluate the **similarity** of two objects in the dataset. I want to satisfy the following condition:

*Two feature vectors which are identical (i.e., they have exactly the same numbers), must have the same similarity value. I already tried different similarity measure, like dot product and cosine similarity, but:*

**Dot product** does not work in my case because the similarity measure depends on the specific numbers in the feature vector. For example given these two objects a=[2, 2, 30, 4, 5], b=[2, 2, 30, 4, 5], then similarity(a, b)=949. Given these two vectors c=[2, 2, 300, 4, 5], d=[2, 2, 300, 4, 5], then similarity(c, d)=90049. I want the similarity to be the same number in both cases, i.e., similarity(a, b) = similarity(c, d);

**Cosine similarity** does not work in my case because it only takes into account the angle between the vectors. I also need to take into account magnitude. For example, given these two objects a=[2, 2, 30, 4, 5], b=[4, 4, 60, 8, 10] then similarity(a, b) = 1 (the maximum similarity). Since the numbers in the feature vectors are different, in my case their similarity should be not the maximum.

Please take into account that my background in statistics is extremely minimal. Links to references in answers are greatly appreciated.

This is taken from a similar question I found while trying to search for a solution.

Comment: does the order of number matter? as in should (1,2,3,4) be same as (4,3,2,1)?

Comment: @Dayne the order of the number does matter yes

Comment: then why don't you simply consider ||x1-x2||, where ||.|| is some p-norm (p can be decided how you want to weight the differences) and x1 and x2 are two vectors.